# Adding programmable current limiting to an MP4688 LED driver

Tags: operational-amplifier, led, driver

I'm trying to build a high quality constant current LED driver, with programmable current limit, and high frequency (20kHz) PWM dimming. The MP4688 (and MP2480) looked like they might fit the bill. The issue is they have a fixed current limit set by a sensing resistor.

No problem, I thought, I'll just use an op-amp to offset the voltage sensed, which will allow me to fool the chip into thinking there's a higher voltage being sensed.

I computed the formula for voltage needed at IADJ0 (given the current limit I wanted, iLED) to be:

```
(.200 - ((1 + 10/82)*(82/92)) * (iLED * 0.200))/(((1 + 10/82)*(10/92)))
```

Made the circuit, tried it out, and it *mostly* works. For values between 50mA and around 400mA, it definitely varies the current limit, although not entirely to the specs of the formula above.

Using a bench power supply, I see the following current being drawn, given the specified current limit programmed:

50 mA -> 126 mA
100 mA -> 220 mA
150 mA -> 257 mA
200 mA -> 293 mA

But less focus on that, because it could be the chip operating at different efficiencies as well which are throwing this numbers off, and I should really be measuring the actual current though the LED.

The two issues I have are:

1. If I vary the input voltage (say from 30V to 24V), the current limit seems to shift (the LED gets dimmer as the voltage decreases, and current draw goes down). This is super confusing to me because the chip is supposed to maintain the current limit across a wide range of voltages, so I can only assume it's something in my op-amp addition.
2. When I raise the current limit to over 400 mA, a few things happen: a) the current limit seems to go down b) the inductor starts buzzing c) occasionally it's like the chip shuts down completely (0 current draw, even though I measure 200mV at the FB pin).

When I simulated the circuit using spice, the whole range worked, but this was just the op-amp portion and not the whole circuit with the MP4688.

I have to assume I screwed up somewhere and either the chip cannot be "fooled" into having a variable current limit or my op-amp selection or circuit is incorrect.

I have looked into other converters such as the LM3409 which seemed quite promising, but even though it has adjustable current limit set by analog voltage input, it varies based on the power supply voltage! I guess the intent is for most of these chips to be used in known and fixed conditions in terms of current limit/power supply, and I want to build something more flexible. But feel free to suggest an alternate chip which might work.

[image: schematic]

Comment: Although the TLV2372 is described as "rail to rail" it won't quite get there, especially at 3.3 V - see the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv2372.pdf?ts=1687519382154) 
for typical and maximum values. The FB pin threshold is only 200 mV and the typical Vol can be a large chunk of that.

Comment: Try this without the OpAmp. Just directly connect the summing point of R7 and R8 to the FB pin. The regulator needs to see the phase correct current ramp.

Comment: @Finbarr good catch! What effect would you expect that to have? Given the hysteretic nature of the converter, I could see the accuracy of set current limit being affected, but would it explain the other weirdness I’m seeing?